# create []array dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Probably this will be a real stupid question to ask but im new in javascript and stuck with dynamic creation of array like in below format:

```
items = [{
    "Date": "2012-01-21T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 7
}, {
    "Date": "2012-01-26T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 10
}, {
    "Date": "2012-05-30T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 16
}];
```

Please guide me how do i create above array dynamically using javascript syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: Dynamically from what? Current answers are as static as your array literal.

Comment: var items = []; for(i in d.date)
    {
     var arr = i.split("-");
     var Item = new function(){
      this.Date = arr[0];
      this.Value = arr[1];
     }
     items.push(Item);}

Answer (score 3):

```
var items = []; // initialize array
items.push({ // add 1st item
  "Date": "2012-01-21T23:45:10.280Z",
  "Value": 7
});
items.push({ // add 2nd item
  "Date": "2012-01-26T23:45:10.280Z",
  "Value": 10
});
items.push({ // add 3rd item
  "Date": "2012-05-30T23:45:10.280Z",
  "Value": 16
});
```

And to view it:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

See:

- Javascript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elememts

Comment: Why do you use `JSON.stringify` for the log?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Just a quick and dirty way to visualize the data's there. You could `console.log(items)` but then you're having to use the debugger to expand out the object and each element in the array to confirm it's been populated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

```
items = [];

items.push({
    "Date": "2012-01-21T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 7
});
items.push({
    "Date": "2012-01-26T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 10
});
items.push({
    "Date": "2012-05-30T23:45:10.280Z",
    "Value": 16
});
```